# How do I use data from a payload array to mutate the state of a reducer?

Tags: react-redux, axios

Say I have an action that gets dispatched to a reducer to change its state and the payload of said action is an array of size 1. How would I address the elements of such an array so that I can mutate the state of the reducer? I've tried
`return { ...state, nameOfElement: action.payload.nameOfElement }`
and I've also tried
`return { ...state, nameOfElement: action.payload[0].nameOfElement }`
but the variable I want to change comes up as undefined in the devtools. The devtools does say that the proper information is being sent in the action payload so I know everything else is working up until I try to assign the data to a state variable. Any ideas?

p.s I am kind of a noob so I apologize in advance if my question is ill-formed.

Comment: Assuming you are assigning it properly, you could be trying to assign it before the data is available. Track the state of when the data is loading and available - then assign the variable when the data is available using.

Comment: How do I check if the data is available?

Comment: Are you getting the data from an API aka a network request or is it something locally? To check you can simply console.log() the data right before you assign it. If you're still having issues repost your question with a minimal reproducible example and I will see if I can help.

Comment: Yes I'm getting the data and it's available. I solved the issue I was having though. Thank you.